# Power supply for raspberry and arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberry-pi3

I have a question regarding the power supply. i have a raspberry pi 3 and arduino uno. Also with powerbank output of 5v 2200mah. whether my powerbank is enough power for both board ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because, albeit being answered, it fits better [arduino.stackexchange.com](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) or, as an alternative, [electronics.stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), and it doesn't comply with [stackoverflow on-topic guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running the two boards with your powerbank should not be any problem. What you have to look out for is the the needed current. Usually, depending on the powerbank, you get 2 A from you powerbank. When you use two usb devices those 2 A are usually split into 1 A per device. From what you are saying about your usage I would not think that you exeed the 1 A per device. But make shure you keep that in mind :)